# didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: is not called for controller which presented modal controller on iOS 5

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, ios5, rotation

There is a view controller (let's name it parent), which presents other view controller (let's name it modal) with `presentModalViewController:animated:`, and then device is rotated. Both controllers support all orientations. Here what's happening:

1. Right after rotation, modal controller receives `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`
2. Just before dismissing modal controller, parent controller receives `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` too. BUT, it happens only if base SDK is set to 4.3 (or lower). If you set base SDK to 5, parent controller DOES NOT receive this message. With 4.3, I updated parent's interface according to new orientation in `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, and it was shown correctly after hiding modal controller, but with iOS 5, it's not called, and parent interface gets messed up after hiding modal controller.

So, what should I do to properly update parent controller's interface to new orientation if device is rotated while modal controller is visible?

Comment: Have the exact same problem. Would be nice to know if anyone has come up with a better solution than the answer above. I don't want my didRotate: code to be called twice.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar problem to this. My solution was to move my orientation handling code into a separate method and call from both the rotation methods and `viewWillAppear:`

```
//.h
@interface SomeViewController

- (void)layoutForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation;

@end


//.m
@implementation SomeViewController


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    UIInterfaceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [self layoutForInterfaceOrientation:currentOrientation];
}

- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [self layoutForInterfaceOrientation:toOrientation];
}

- (void)layoutForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {

    // layout views
}

@end
```

Comment: I thought about something like this, but I have many places which use `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:`, and replacing all of them with other methods would take a lot of time and is error-prone. Such behavior in iOS 5 seems like a bug to me, since it doesn't allow us to rely on `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` being called if orientation changes.

Comment: You could still do the same thing, but call `[self layoutForInterfaceOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]]` from your `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` methods.

Comment: I use your solution Ell, but it's not the best, because when rotation without showing any modal view, then your parent view execute 2 times that rotation code. Does anyone have a better idea? nyway, thanks a lot Ell.

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the issue. It worked for me:

```
modal.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```